# host: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed

Tags: linux, parsing, dns, host, nameservers

I'm getting an error and I cannot see what happens, please see if you can catch what's wrong.

Whenever I use the "host" command, I get this error:

```
xavi@cobalto:~$ host www.guparty.com
host: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed
```

I think the syntax is correct:

```
xavi@cobalto:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search dsitelecom.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Also permissions are readable for everybody:

```
xavi@cobalto:~$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 49 2011-10-30 12:02 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Probably it is a silly thing but I cannot get it. Do you see anything wrong there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your syntax, you need to define one nameserver per line in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
search dsitelecom.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 4):

I saw the same error when by mistake *nix EOLs ("\n") were replaced with windows ones ("\r\n"). Solution: `dos2unix filename`

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, but did this and got working:

```
# mv resolv.conf resolv.conf.old
# cat resolv.conf.old
search example.com
domain example.com
nameserver 11.22.33.44
nameserver 2000::1
# echo "search example.com" >>resolv.conf
# echo "domain example.com" >>resolv.conf
# echo "nameserver 11.22.33.44" >>resolv.conf
# echo "nameserver 2000::1" >>resolv.conf
```

The addresses are just example, but the result is working. Why copy resolv.conf is that you get a copy of original. Then when you print it out, you dont have to remember everything inside resolv.conf. And when you make the file with echos, you can be sure that there is no extra chars those make troubles. So echo all nameserver lines to there.

Comment: You don't need IPv6 name server.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue in WSL2, but my resolv.conf was definitely in the correct format. I even hexdumped it to verify that the line endings were correct. Following the below fixed it:

1. Find out nameserver with windows powershell using ipconfig.exe
2. Use `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf` to add:

```
[network]                                                                        
generateResolvConf = false
```

4. Restart wsl (Windows powershell) using `wsl --shutdown`
5. Open WSL and take a backup of `/etc/resolv.conf`. Then remove it via `rm -f /etc/resolv.conf`
6. Add new file `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf` with:

```
nameserver X.X.X.X
```

7. Restart wsl (Windows powershell) using `wsl --shutdown`
8. Open WSL and remove using `wget google.com` and test some you corporate domain.

Adapted from https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1350#issuecomment-1187571290